# Create nested mutation graphql field not provided

Tags: javascript, graphql, prism

I am trying to create a user with a profile simultaneously in my mutation like this :

```
mutation {
   addUser(
     input: {
       firstName: "Jane"
       lastName: "Doe"
       roleId: "bfb3d29a-379e-4558-b2fd-af98b666c100"
       username: "jdoe"
       email: "janedoe@gmail.com"
       password: "1234567890"
       profile: {
            create: {
                addressOne: "Runda, Kenya"
                addressTwo: "Murang'a, Kenya"
                dob: "12-12-1990"
                zip: "22333-00100"
          }
       }
     }
   ) {
     id
     firstName
     lastName
     profile {
        id
      dob
    }
   }
 }
```

Unfortunately, i keep getting the error `"message": "Field \"addProfileInput.addressOne\" of required type \"String!\" was not provided.",`  
My mutation looks like :

```
signUp: async (_, { input }) => {
          const password = await hash(input.password, 10);
          const newUser = await prisma.user.create({
            data: {
              firstName: input.firstName,
              middleName: input.middleName,
              lastName: input.lastName,
              roleId: input.roleId,
              username: input.username,
              email: input.email,
              password,
              profile: {
                create: {
                  addressOne: input.addressOne,
                  addressTwo: input.addressTwo,
                  zip: input.zip,
                  dob: input.dob,
                },
              },
            },
            include: {
              profile: {
                select: {
                  dob: true,
                },
              },
            },
          });
          return newUser;
        },
```

And in my `schema.graphql` i have `type Mutation {signUp(input: addUserInput!): AuthPayload}`  where the `addUserInput` type has these definition
:

```
input addUserInput {
  firstName: String!
  middleName: String
  lastName: String
  username: String!
  email: String
  roleId: String!
  password: String
  profile: addProfileInput
}

input addProfileInput {
  addressOne: String!
  addressTwo: String!
  zip: String!
  dob: String!
}
```

How should i define my mutation to create both the user and the profile at the same time instead of having two different mutations ? Any recommendations or links to read will be appreciated.

Comment: try use `profile: {addressOne: ..., addressTwo: ...}` in your mutation

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `create: { }` level in your input and just send:

```
profile: {
  addressOne: input.addressOne,
  addressTwo: input.addressTwo,
  zip: input.zip,
  dob: input.dob,
},
```